# dialogflow v2 extracting parameters in fullfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es

i am using my dialogflow over facebook messenger and passing a parameter. i am able to extract it but not sure why it is not a string.

the code looks like below

```
function botHandler(agent) {
    console.log("inside bot handler request body is:" + 
     JSON.stringify(request.body.queryResult.parameters));
    const adParams = request.body.queryResult.parameters;
    let state = adParams.stateName;

    state = state.toString().toUperCase()
```

the error it throws is

```
TypeError: state.toString(...).toUperCase is not a function
    at botHandler (/srv/index.js:52:30)
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:303:44)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:114:9)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

the value is there but not sure why toString fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toString()` is not failing (tho it probably is unnecessary, since it is likely a string already).

Your method `toUpercase()` is failing because you have a typo in "uppercase". It should have two "p"s, not one. `toUppercase()`.

That said, as Mathais noted, you should make sure you have the `stateName` parameter first.

Comment: @MoblizeIT happens to all of us

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest extracting parameters like this in your fulfillment:

```
 function botHandler(agent) {
        let state = agent.parameters["stateName"];
        let uState = state.toUpperCase();
        let answer = "So you live in " + uState + "?";

        agent.add(answer);
    }
```

And you can check if the parameter is present this way:

```
if (agent.parameters["stateName"]) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

Hope this helps!